# Getting Yahoo Biz Industry Market Summary Stock Info

Tags: javascript, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I am using this code to get Stock Info for a Symbol which is working for me!

```
 var symbol = "AAPL";
 var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20' + symbol + '%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   console.log(data.query.results.quote.Ask);
   });
```

but I also need to get the `Industry Market Summary` for the categories from the [Yahoo Business Page](https://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html) like getting Market summer for Gold in [INDUSTRY CENTER - GOLD Page](https://biz.yahoo.com/ic/134.html)

[image]

Can you please let me know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following yql query to select data regarding materials.

**for Gold**

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("^YHOh714")
```

from [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3DYHOh714&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22%5EYHOh714%22%29) get the REST query

**for Copper**

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("^YHOh711")
```

from [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3DYHOh714&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22%5EYHOh711%22%29) get the REST query